# Identification of round, keyed, two-pin high power connector

Tags: batteries, connector, identification

I just got a new electric bike and I'm thinking about adding an extra 36V 20Ah battery to get more range.

What I'm thinking is to pull out the main battery when it runs out and connect the second battery to the port which the main battery connects to.

This is the port on the body of the bike:

[image]

And this is the port on the main battery

[image]

But for that I need a male connector same as the main battery. I don't know what it's called; does anyone know? I did Google it but I guess I don't even know what to look for...

Comment: Dimensions and pin depth measurements would be helpful. Do you have a caliber?

Comment: The Diameter of the circle is 1 cm and the pin is about 9mm tall sorry I don't even know what a caliber is

Comment: He means "caliper", I think - a measuring tool.

Comment: I suspect the brass posts below the circular connector are the high-current connections to the battery.  The round connector may be for charging or temperature measurement.  Are there sockets in the battery that would mate with the posts in the top picture?

Comment: The second photo is the connector on the battery. The first one is on the body of the bike. It's a Xiaomi HIMO C20 if it helps... And this is the battery that  I want to have as an extra https://m.fr.aliexpress.com/item/4000382065486.html

Comment: Can you show a not-quite-so-closeup picture of the battery connector area so we can see if there are holes in the battery that would mate with the brass posts by the bike connector?  I suspect those posts are the terminals that will carry the high current to the motor.

Comment: There are no other connector on the batter or on the bike frame https://ibb.co/R3884Ct
https://ibb.co/XbM7fxB those 2 metal thingies are some kind of a holder or a lock they've got nothing to do with electricity